# NoMethodError in Awards#index

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am just starting on rails and found a problem which I can't solve. I am creating a simple app with two models (awards and students). `:award has_one :student` and `:student belongs_to :award`

I was told that in app/views/awards/ in show.html.erb, replace:

```
<%= @award.student_id %>
```

with:

```
<%= @award.student.given_name %> <%= @award.student.family_name %>
```

and in index.html.erb, replace:

```
<%= award.student_id %>
```

with:

```
<%= award.student.given_name %> <%= award.student.family_name %>
```

after this the localhost:3000/students is working fine but localhost:3000/awards is not working and giving following error :-

```
**NoMethodError in Awards#index**

Showing /home/redblink/rbtest/students/app/views/awards/index.html.erb where line #17 raised:

undefined method `given_name' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #17):

14:   <tr>
15:     <td><%= award.name %></td>
16:     <td><%= award.year %></td>
17:     <td><%= award.student.given_name %> <%= award.student.family_name %></td>
18:     <td><%= link_to 'Show', award %></td>
19:     <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_award_path(award) %></td>
20:     <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', award, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

please reply asap with the solution.....

Comment: Your `award.student` is `nil`. Do check that the particular award belongs to a student.

Comment: yes, i've done it in models/award.rb already :-

class Award < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :student_id, :year
# every award is linked to a student, through student_id
belongs_to :student
end

Comment: What do u mean by u hv done it in award.rb??? what u have done??

Comment: in models/award.rb i wrote already :- belongs_to :student

Comment: @user1571530 Update your question with Award and Student models. You need to go through [The Rails Guides on Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: models/Student.rb --------------- --------------- class Award < ActiveRecord::Base attr_accessible :name, :student_id, :year # every award is linked to a student, through student_id belongs_to :student end ---------------- models/award.rb ---------------- class Student < ActiveRecord::Base attr_accessible :date_of_birth, :family_name, :given_name, :grade_point_average, :middle_name, :start_date # a student can have many awards has_many :awards end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there is one of the `awards` record whose corresponding `students` record is not present so its returning `nil` and u can call `given_name` on nil.

So you can handle it as:

Write following:

`<%= award.student ? award.student.given_name : '' %> <%= award.student ? award.student.family_name : '' %>`

instead of

`<%= award.student.given_name %> <%= award.student.family_name %>`

Comment: where am i supposed to write this..??

Comment: whereu have written `<%= award.student.given_name %> <%= award.student.family_name %>` ???   in ur index.html.erb